# Radiation pattern in the patternCustom Matlab function not showing up

Tags: matlab, plot

I am working on an antenna array for a university project. The antenna is designed for a centre frequency of 2.44175 GHz, and should span the Wi-Fi spectrum from 2.4 GHz to 2.4835 GHz. As a part of this project I have gotten the antenna tested in a MVG SG24 for a sweep of frequencies from 2.4 GHz to 2.5 GHz, with 10 MHz increments. The resulting data has then been placed in a CSV file that is being used as a source in MatLab.

When calling the patternCustom function in MatLab, the magnitude of the signal, theta angle and phi angle are being used to create a 3-dimensional radiation pattern, with a colour graph denoting signal reflection. I am however just getting an empty 3-dimensional plot, without any data bar the colour graph. I don't know if anyone here has experienced anything similar, but any help is greatly appreciated.

I have attached an image of the expected result and my result. Alongside this I have attached the CSV file I am using as a source for the program, and the code I am running.

I have tried to use MatLab's own guide on how to implement external antenna data, and would expect to get a 3-dimension radiation pattern. I am however just getting an empty plot without any data.

[File I am using as a source for the data in MatLab.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MfXjW1JgfWpbZ5ppPZ_7I6iLbeLa421o/view?usp=sharing)

**Code I am running:**

```
opts = detectImportOptions("Antenna Array Spherical data_Polar H_Polar V_Polar Θ_Polar Ф_E Total.csv");
opts.DataLines = 3;
opts.VariableNamesLine = 2;
patchData = readmatrix("Antenna Array Spherical data_Polar H_Polar V_Polar Θ_Polar Ф_E Total.csv",opts)
realTheta= patchData(:,8)
realPhi = patchData(:,10)
magnitudeE = patchData(:,12)
patternCustom(magnitudeE,realTheta,realPhi)
```

[**Image of expected result, from MatLab's own article on the patternCustom function.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2b7qS.png)

[**Image of the plot I am getting.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAqzR.png)

Comment: need access to data

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux hey, sorry was asleep when you made the request, you should have access now.

Comment: ok, tried it and apparently have no Antenna package. From data inspection, are you sure magintudes shold be negative?

Comment: Yeah, when it comes to the gain measurement, those are usually negative for antennas, since the value is in dBm.

Answer (score 0):

ok, got access to the antenna package

First, I think your angular units are wrong, looks like radians and needed degrees

Second, your theta,phi grid is highly irregular

This is how theta,phi plot looks like for antenna example from Matlab

[image]

nice regular sweep of the 180 degrees in both theta and phi

And this is how your grid looks like converted to degrees, doesn't look right

[image]